# c++ loop where the value of the object decreases until a certain point

Tags: c++

I would like to Create a loop where the value of the object decreases until a certain point (until -20) by increments of -10 and the resets to original point.

```
float asteroid1Yorigin = 1100.00f;
float asteroid1Y = asteroid1Yorigin;


for (asteroid1Y = asteroid1Yorigin; asteroid1Y < -20; asteroid1Y--) {
            asteroid1Y - 10.1f;
            cout << asteroid1Y;
        }
        //after this I would like the point of asteroid1Y to reset to origin
```

Comment: ... and your question is? "I'd like to..." is not a question. It is a statement of your intentions. You've described what your intentions are, now what is your specific question?

Comment: My question is why doesn't this particular code work? and how would I go about making it work?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? You initialized `asteroid1Yorigin` to 1100. Your `for` loop only runs when `asteroid1Yorigin` is less than -20. 1100 is not less than -20, it is greater than -20. Therefore your `for` loop doesn't execute. You need to keep in mind the Golden Rule Of Computer Programming. Your computer will always do exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do. So, which part of this "doesn't work"? Does your computer, somehow, execute what's in the `for` loop? If so, you need to [edit] your question, and show a [mre].

Comment: For one thing, `asteroid1Y - 10.1f;` is a statement with no effect (it doesn't do anything). Any chance you mean something like `asteroid1Y -= 10.0f;`, which actually subtracts from the asteroid value?

Comment: maybe you meant `asteroid1Y >= -20` or something. The loop runs while the condition is true.

Comment: also it is not clear why you have the `--` as well as the attempted subtraction of 10.1

Comment: Ok seems I didn't fully understand the loop syntax, thanks all for clearing that up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `asteroid1Y - 10.1f;` to `asteroid1Y -= 10.0f;` (don't know why it was 10.1, as you wanted to decrement it by 10) as at the moment it does not have any effect. This is because equation `x -= y;` is equal to `x = x - y;`. The less/more sign has been also changed, as you want to decrement the value of `asteroid1Y` when it is bigger than `-20`, otherwise (with `asteroid1Y < -20` condition) the loop will not work, as `1100.0f < -20` is always false.

Also think about changing your loop to

```
while (asteroid1Y > -20)
{
    asteroid1Y -= 10.0f;
    std::cout << asteroid1Y << std::endl;
}
```

because with the only change I wrote you would change the value twice in every iteration of the loop. If you want to stay with for loop, that should do the job:

```
for (asteroid1Y = asteroid1Yorigin; asteroid1Y > -20; asteroid1Y -= 10) 
{
    std::cout << asteroid1Y << std::endl;
}
```

In that case you do not have to change the `asteroid1Y` value inside the loop, as it is already changing because of last part of for.

Comment: The type of `asteroid1Y` should also be an integer type, not a floating point type. For small numbers you won't have any issue, but with larger initial values, you will run into trouble and worst case this becomes an infinite loop.